# CSS background colour change on hover not working?

Tags: html, css, hover

I've been trying to figure out why my :hover property isn't working. I don't know if there is just something really simple I'm missing. I have a Div acting as an empty rectangle of colour that I want to change when I hover over it, but nothing happens when I do. Here is the code:

CSS

```
#leftcontainer {
    width: 560px;
    height: 480px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#rightcontainer {
    width: 370px;
    height: 480px;
    float: left;
}

#index1 {
    width: 560px;
    height: 195px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
}

#index1:hover {
    background-colour: #e6ffea;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="bodycontent">
    <div id="leftcontainer">
        <div id="index1"></div>
        <div id="index2"></div>
        <div id="index3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightcontainer">
        <div id="index4"></div>
        <div id="index5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misspelling `background-color`. The spec uses American English.

Comment: which is horrible if you ask me.

Comment: What should it use? @rlemon I'm in favour of `couleur`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
background-color: #e6ffea;
```

It's `color`, no `colour`.

Answer (score 0):

Error is in your `CSS` file.

```
#index1:hover {
  background-colour: #e6ffea;
}
```

Should be

```
#index1:hover {
  background-color: #e6ffea;
}
```